# When do I have to declare a function used in a template?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I've got (probably) a simple question.
When do I have to declare a function used in a template?
The following code prints out (using gcc >=4.1):

> init my A object
>
> no init

Using gcc 4.0 the following code prints out:

> init my A object
>
> init my string object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void init(T& t){
        std::cout << "no init" << std::endl;
}

// void init(std::string& t);

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T& t){
        init(t);
        // do some further stuff
}

void init(std::string& t){
        std::cout << "init my string object" << std::endl;
}


class A{

};

void init(A& t){
        std::cout << "init my A object" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
        A a;
        doSomething(a);
        std::string s("test");
        doSomething(s);
        return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between the usage of std::string and A?
Shouldn't there be the same behaviour?

With the additional forward declaration it works fine,
but when do I need it?

Cheers,
CSpille

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396458/confusing-function-lookup-with-templates-in-c for a similar ordering issue and explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions at the instantiation point are looked up only using argument dependent lookup (looking up functions in the namespaces associated with a function argument). Normal lookup is only done at the point of the template definition.

So for `std::string`, only the generic `init` function template is visible and called, since there is no specific one for it in namespace `std`. For `A`, the more specific function is found in the global namespace of `A`.

If you forward declare the string specific function to appear prior to `doSomething`, normal unqualified lookup finds it at the definition and uses it later on.

If you call `init` as follows, it inhibits argument dependent lookup, and will thus use the generic template for `A` too.

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(T& t){
    (init)(t);
    // won't do ADL
}
```

(As a side-node: In that case, not only argument dependent lookup is inhibited at instantiation, but `init` won't be a dependent name in the first place - only non-parenthesized and unqualified function names are made dependent. Thus only non-ADL lookup at definition is done anyway and no lookup at instantiation is taken place what-so-ever, even if there would be a form different from ADL that would be done there.)

Comment: Great answer! thx! DANKE!
Do you probably know, how this "(init)(t);" is called? non-ADL lookup?
Are there other cases, when brackets around the function are useful?

Comment: @CSpille, they are useful to inhibit a function-like macro invocation too. But inhibiting ADL is the only other purpose i know. As far as i know, wrapping the function name in parentheses doesn't have a special name :)