# How to overload operator>> for bool

Tags: yaml-cpp

I want to parse scalar as bool.
This example works:

```
#include <yaml.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void operator>> (const YAML::Node & node, bool & b)
{
    std::string tmp;
    node >> tmp;
     std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
    b = (tmp == "1") || (tmp == "yes");
}

int main()
{
    bool b1, b2;
    std::stringstream ss("key: да\notherkey: no");
    YAML::Parser parser(ss);
    YAML::Node doc;
    parser.GetNextDocument(doc);

    doc["key"] >> b1;
    doc["otherkey"] >> b2;

    std::cout << b1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << b2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But in more complicated case template operator is used:

```
YAML::operator>><bool> (node=..., value=@0x63f6e8) at /usr/include/yaml-cpp/nodeimpl.h:24
```

And I get 'YAML::InvalidScalar' if string in not 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: Wow. I surrounded my overloaded operator in namespace YAML{}. And now it works...

Answer (score 0):

yaml-cpp already reads `bool`s by default, as specified by the YAML spec.

> y, yes, true, on

produce `true`, and

> n, no, false, off

produce `false`. If you want to extend or change this behavior (for example, so that "да" also produces `true`), as you found out, overloading `operator >>` in the `YAML` namespace works.

The reason it needs to be in the `YAML` namespace (but only for "more complicated examples" - meaning where you don't directly call `operator >>` with a `bool` argument) is the way C++ lookup works.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396458/confusing-function-lookup-with-templates-in-c/1402325#1402325) to [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396458/confusing-function-lookup-with-templates-in-c) for a great explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I just want a localized version, e. g. "да" in Russian